# Express Sequelize, Does not Throw error when specifying wrong column name in create

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

TestTb.ts

```js
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize'
import sequelize from './../config/dbMysql'

export default sequelize.define(
    'tbTest',
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        tStamp: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE
        }
    },
    {
        tableName: 'tbTest'
    }
)
```

```js
import TestTb from '../models/TestTb'
export const createPost = async (req: Request, res: Response) => { 
        const jane = await TestTb.create({ wrongColumn: 'new row from node ' }) 
}
```

When I try to create a new record with a wrong column name, it then proceeds to saving a new column with 'null' to name column.

Is there a definition in sequelize so the call would return an error? even better if typescript detects that the column itself is not defined.

thanks

Comment: Just define and use models using classes and helper types like CreationOptional, InferAttributes and InferCreationAttributes